# Isolate variable in inequality

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I'm having the most stupid of problems. Suppose I have a simple inequality like
$$ |2-x|>2.$$

The solution to this is

$$ x<0 , \,x>4.$$

This is pretty obvious, though Mathematica insists on spitting back the input:

```
Reduce[Abs[2 - x] > 2]
```

outputs

```
Abs[2 - x] > 2
```

How can I tell Mathematica I want a series of expression with only $x$ on the LHS? Trying to solve for $x$ only makes Mathematica complain that the solution is full-dimensional, I assume this means that Solve can only output single points and not intervals. I also suspect this has to do with the fact that Mathematica doesn't really know $x$ is real, but

```
FullSimplify[Reduce[Abs[2-x] > 2], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

produces the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
Reduce[Abs[2 - x] > 2, x, Reals]
(*x < 0 || x > 4*)
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks, exactly what I needed. I'll accept when the 10 minutes pass.

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome

Answer (score 4):

I always avoid using `Abs` since it is a Complex Function. Here we use `RealAbs`

```
Reduce[RealAbs[2 - x] > 2]
```

Comment: Also, `Reduce[Sqrt[(2-x)^2] > 2, x]`